# Beer Tasting probabilities

Tags: probability

I am going to have a beer tasting competition at my place soon. My hypothesis is that people are full of crap when they say beer A is so much better B. Basically my hypothesis is that all beer tastes the same.

I have 5 beers.

What is the average number of beers they will get correct purely based on chance?

For the first beer it would be 1/5, then the next would also be 1/5? Do I just add the probabilities together?

Sorry if this is a pretty easy probability question, but the beer competition starts next week, and I need some hard maths!

Comment: If you assume that a drinker may guess the same label twice in a row, the probability is of course $1/5$. If you assume that he guesses only among the other labels, the probability is still $1/5$ but the argument is a bit subtler.

Comment: There is a probability of 1 that this will be delicious.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand the problem correctly, you have five (distinguishable) beers, and each person guesses the beer type by chance. Then, each beer type has probability $\frac{1}{5}$.

Now, if the person guesses each of the 5 beers *independently* (which would be the case if he didn't get feedback from you on which type he drank), then the number of correct guesses could be modeled as the random variable $X$, which in this case would be binomially distributed with parameters $n=5$ and $p=\frac{1}{5}$.

The probability of guessing $k$ of the beer types correctly would then be

\begin{equation}
P(X=k) = \binom{5}{k} \left(\frac{1}{5} \right)^k \left(\frac{4}{5} \right)^{5-k}
\end{equation}

The average number of correct guesses is then the mean of $X$, which is $E[X] = np = 5 \cdot \frac{1}{5} = 1$.